# Most efficient way to calculate an expectation value of a noisy model in Qiskit

Tags: qiskit, simulation, noise

I want to classically simulate quantum circuits with noise. This noise can be a custom one (`noise.NoiseModel()`) or a fake quantum computer (`QasmSimulator.from_backend(FakeMontreal()`).
I want to calculate the expectation value of an observable, for example $\langle Z \rangle$ of the first qubit with a finite amount of shots.

I tried different scripts and the computational time is order of magnitude larger than the equivalent codes for ideal quantum circuits (like 10x or more).
If I understood correctly, it creates multiple instances of the circuit (one for each shot) and each instance is a different quantum circuit (different because, for example, new gates are added with a probability that depends on the noise model).

What's the way to do that in the most efficient way with Qiskit or other libraries?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal working example of the quantity you want to achieve? For simple noise models, I think this can be more efficient without Qiskit. Also, how many qubits do you want to use in your real use case? And what is your target evaluation time?

Comment: @TristanNemoz I would like to simulate quantum circuits with 14 qubits in a time comparable with the simulation of ideal circuits (1s for my old pc). I'm interested in simple noise models (depolarizing, bitflip, phaseflip, etc.). The problem is that with 1000 shots, the best I can do is more than 30 seconds for 14 qubits.

Comment: How deep is your circuit typically, excluding noise operations?

Comment: @TristanNemoz it has 30 Ry gates per qubit (so 30*14 single qubit gates for circuits with 14 qubits) and 30 CNOT gates per neighobur pairs (so 30*13 CNOTs for circuits with 14 qubits).

Comment: And the way you apply your noise model (e.g. the depolarizing one) is by applying a noise gate after each gate that you apply, correct?

Comment: I've tested using Kraus operators, but the computation still seems to be painfully slow even for very simple circuits. I think your best shot is to open an issue on the Qiskit GitHub to ask whether there's a solution, or to ask for the implementation of such a feature. Note however that it is expected that any simulator will be at least a bit slow on this task on a medium computer: we're still talking about 16384x16384 matrices after all

Comment: Indeed, either you use the statevector method, but in this case you have to regenerate the circuit each time (and you would need a very large number of shots to take into accounts all possible combinations of errors), or you use the density matrix and Kraus superoperators formalislm, but your computer has then to deal with very large matrices before doing any meaningful computations on it. This is probably the method you want to go with however, since it requires a heavy computation once, but is far more accurate than the methods with shots

Comment: @TristanNemoz Thank you, these are the same approaches that I tried. I'm okay on having a finite amount of shots (from the accuracy point of view), but it has a large computational cost. Same for the density matrix formalism when I have many qubits. I will try to ask on Qiskit GitHub, thank you again!